# Creating Bundle Product with REST API issue

Tags: magento2, rest-api, bundled-product

This is my request to `rest/V1/products`:

```
{
   "product":{
      "sku":"test4",
      "name":"test json",
      "attribute_set_id":4,
      "price":10,
      "status":1,
      "visibility":4,
      "type_id":"bundle",
      "custom_attributes":[
         {
            "attribute_code":"price_view",
            "value":0
         },
         {
            "attribute_code":"custom_recipe",
            "value":1
         },
         {
            "attribute_code":"url_key",
            "value":"test4"
         }
      ],
      "extension_attributes":{
         "website_ids":[
            1
         ],
         "bundle_product_options":[
            {
               "title":"Container Type",
               "required":true,
               "type":"select",
               "position":0,
               "sku":"test4",
               "product_links":[
                  {
                     "sku":"sku-1",
                     "qty":1,
                     "position":0,
                     "is_default":false,
                     "price":0,
                     "price_type":0,
                     "can_change_quantity":0
                  },
                  {
                     "sku":"sku-2",
                     "qty":1,
                     "position":1,
                     "is_default":false,
                     "price":0,
                     "price_type":0,
                     "can_change_quantity":0
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],
         "stock_item":{
            "qty":1,
            "is_in_stock":true
         }
      }
   },
   "saveOptions":true
}
```

I have my product saved, but the price fields are missing for the options. See img:
[image]

I have another **bundle** product, where the price option is there. See img:
[image]

My question or issue is what should i change in my json request to have the price option ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please update the payload and pass the price value to the associated product

"product_links":[
{
"sku":"sku-1",
"qty":1,
"position":0,
"is_default":false,
"price":0,
"price_type":0,
"can_change_quantity":0
},
{
"sku":"sku-2",
"qty":1,
"position":1,
"is_default":false,
"price":0,
"price_type":0,
"can_change_quantity":0
}
]